# How to assign a Ref to a button in a React component if I don't own that code? I want to focus it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I'm working on React. There's another team which exposes us a component which has a button in it. It is a dependency for our repository. I want that button to be focused when a particular action is done. I want to do it using refs or any other acceptable way.

`myCode.js`

```
focusExternalButton() {
  // some code that focuses the button in the external component
}

render() {

  return {
    <div>
      <ExternalButtonComponent/>
      <button onClick={this.focusExternalButton}>submit</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

`ExternalButtonComponent.js`

```
render() {
  return <div><button id="btn-external">This is a button</button></div>
}
```

How do I put focus on the external button when I click my button? I'm thinking of refs but I'm not sure how I can achieve it.

Comment: What library is the button part of? Have you read the docs? Quite possible there is a built in solution already.

Comment: That library is owned by another team in my organization. I can ask them to expose a ref for that. But before I reach out to them I just want to ensure there's no other way. @pilchard

Comment: You can't use a ref because it will be ignored by button component if it's not configured to receive one. Also, there is no guarantee that the internal structure of the returned HTML will stay consistent. A hacky way to achieve it would be to query the button in a `useLayoutEffect` but if you have the option of getting a ref exposed that would be *much* preferable.

Comment: @pilchard what are your thoughts on using document.getElementById('target-id').focus()? Is that an okay way to focus it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It surprises me a little that the external component uses `id`s as rendering it more than once in a page will lead to duplicate `id`s on the page which isn't valid HTML.

Nonetheless, yes, you can query the DOM directly, though I would probably do this once on mount and store the result returned element in a `ref`.

```js
const { useEffect, useRef } = React;

function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    buttonRef.current = document.getElementById('btn-external');
  }, []);

  function focusExternalButton() {
    buttonRef.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ExternalButtonComponent label="This is a button" />
      <button type='button' onClick={focusExternalButton}>submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function ExternalButtonComponent({label}) {
  return <div><button id="btn-external">{label}</button></div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
#btn-external:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(21, 156, 228, 0.4);}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

However, to avoid having to do this every time you use the component you can wrap the external component and [forward the ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

```
const WrappedExternalButtonComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = document.getElementById('btn-external');
  }, []);

  return <ExternalButtonComponent {...props} />
});
```

```js
const { useEffect, useRef, forwardRef } = React;

const WrappedExternalButtonComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = document.getElementById('btn-external');
  }, []);

  return <ExternalButtonComponent {...props} />
});

function ExternalButtonComponent({label}) {
  return <div><button id="btn-external">{label}</button></div>;
}

function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef();

  function focusExternalButton() {
    buttonRef.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <WrappedExternalButtonComponent ref={buttonRef} label="This is a button" />
      <button type='button' onClick={focusExternalButton}>submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
#btn-external:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(21, 156, 228, 0.4);}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Or even generalize it further by creating a utility that takes a `Component` and a query function as arguments and returns a wrapped component.

```
const wrapExternalComponent = (Component, query) => forwardRef(({ children, ...props }, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = query();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Component {...props}>
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
});

const WrappedExternalButtonComponent = 
  wrapExternalComponent(ExternalButtonComponent, () => document.getElementById('btn-external'));
```

```js
const { useEffect, useRef, forwardRef } = React;

const wrapExternalComponent = (Component, query) => forwardRef(({ children, ...props }, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = query();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Component {...props}>
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
});

function ExternalButtonComponent({label}) {
  return <div><button id="btn-external">{label}</button></div>;
}

const WrappedExternalButtonComponent = 
  wrapExternalComponent(ExternalButtonComponent, () => document.getElementById('btn-external'));

function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef();

  function focusExternalButton() {
    buttonRef.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <WrappedExternalButtonComponent ref={buttonRef} label="This is a button" />
      <button type='button' onClick={focusExternalButton}>submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}





ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
#btn-external:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(21, 156, 228, 0.4);}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Very helpful. Regarding you being surprised by the id - it's actually dynamically generated based on a prop, but I missed mentioning that while trying to simplify.

Comment: Ah, I see that makes more sense, happy to help.